# Asignar imagen de un img a otro

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy intentando asignar una imagen desde un elemento `img` a otro  elemento `img`.

```
if ($('#e1').prop('checked')  ) {
    alert("Chequeado")
    var url = $(pg1).attr('src');
    alert(url)
    $("lbl11img").attr("src", url);
}
```

Con los `alert`, compruebo que el elemento se ha seleccionado, y que la `URL` de la propiedad `SRC` es correcta...

No consigo que funcione... Alguna sugerencia?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label id='lbl1'>Ha elegido pagar con:</label>
        </td>
        <td id='lbl11'>
            <img id='lbl11img' src='' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;' > 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A grandes rasgos, logro identificar que te falta definir el selector que estás tratando de capturar y/o de asignar.

Por ejemplo, en `var url = $(pg1).attr('src');`, no hay un selector definido en `pg1`, al igual que en `$("lbl11img").attr("src", url);`.

Agregué un par de líneas en el código para recrear el comportamiento esperado.

```js
if ($('#e1').prop('checked')) {
  console.log("Chequeado")
  var url = $('#pg1').attr('src');
  console.log(url)
  $("#lbl11img").attr("src", url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img id='pg1' src='https://picsum.photos/30' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'>
      <label id='lbl1'>Ha elegido pagar con:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="e1" checked>
    </td>
    <td id='lbl11'>
      <img id='lbl11img' src='' style='width: 30px; height: 30px;'>       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cierto, este código va como '<?php include 'proceso.php'; ?> en otro archivo donde, si están esos  selectores